# Unable to redirect output from bash

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to run a command through PHP for a project and have the output redirected to a file.

On PHP, I'm creating a string and running the shell_exec() function with the string as a parameter:

```
$command = "my_commands";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

To be able to run things as root through PHP and shell_exec, I use the following:

```
bash -lc 'echo **my_linux_password** | /usr/bin/sudo -S **my_commands** &'
```

An example of this is as follows:

```
bash -lc 'echo **my_linux_password** | /usr/bin/sudo ... &' 2>&1 | tee /home/kali/Desktop/logs/file.txt
```

(See end of code above) Am I putting the `2>&1 | tee /home/kali/Desktop/logs/file.txt` in the right place? I don't seem to be getting any files created. The command works just fine without this output redirect part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the sudo command in the background, so the "outer" bash process does not receive the output for redirection.

You'll have to do something like

```
bash -lc 'echo **my_linux_password** | /usr/bin/sudo sh -c "my_command | tee /home/kali/Desktop/logs/file.txt 2>&1" &'
```

And you're now firmly in quoting hell.